# Chrome Extensions import CSS framework will make effect to the loaded page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script, browser-extension

I tried to use the `content scripts` to make an popup page by `Vue.js` and `Bootstrap` the popup page works good, but the side effect of this let the original website components setting become a chaos. I used `es6` and compile by `webpack`.

As following my code:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
import 'animate.css/animate.min.css';

//component
import App from './App.vue';

//scripts


Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.config.silent = true;




var initDom = document.createElement("div");
initDom.id = "extensionUIwrap";

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(initDom);

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#extensionUIwrap')
```

How to let the css module just made effect on my popup page or exclude effect from the original website?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to really isolate stylesheets in the Google Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783217/how-to-really-isolate-stylesheets-in-the-google-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Vue inside [shadow dom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM), like explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47190115/2122529).

It will completely isolate your extension's DOM from pages.

Comment: how to let `vue app` inside `shadow dom`?  After the code `new Vue()` the dom `#extensionUIwrap ` will be replaced by App content which is `<template><div id="app"></div></template>`